# Infinite Loop Smooth Vertical Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML table structure of data and I was able to get to loop in a vertical list with some javascript but I can't figure out how to make it a smooth constant vertical scroll, right now it goes 1 by 1 when the row reaches the top and gets appended to itself. Even having setInterval set to 0, it has a brief annoying pause. Also, my slice of 10 doesn't seem to keep the list to 10 sometimes, not sure if this is my JavaScript or a browser issue.

> JS

```
$.fn.infiniteScrollUp=function(){
    var self=this,kids=self.children()
    kids.slice(10).hide()
    setInterval(function(){
        kids.filter(':hidden').eq(0).slideDown()
        kids.eq(0).slideUp(function(){
            $(this).appendTo(self)
            kids=self.children()
        })
    },1)
    return this
}


$(function(){
    $('section').infiniteScrollUp()
})
```

> HTML

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <div>
      <span>a</span>
      <span>b</span>
      <span>c</span>
      <span>d</span>
    </div>
  </thead>
  <section>
    <div><span>a</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>b</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>c</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>d</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>e</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>f</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>g</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>h</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>i</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>j</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>k</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>l</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>m</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>n</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>o</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>p</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>q</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>r</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>s</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>t</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>u</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>v</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>w</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>x</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>y</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
    <div><span>z</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
  </section>
</table>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pfpyc68e/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/pfpyc68e/1/

```
var self=this,kids=self.children()
setInterval(function(){
        kids.slice(10).hide()
    kids.filter(':hidden').eq(0).slideDown()
    kids.eq(0).slideUp(800, "linear",function(){
        $(this).appendTo(self)
        kids=self.children()
    })
},1)
```

Added a 800 millisecond timer on slideUp and then moved the slice inside of the interval. At the least the move of the slice is what you need. I'm not sure if that is the right sliding motion you're going for...

Comment: That was exactly what I was going for. Thanks Cayce K!!

Comment: Cayce - I am dynamically adding and removing elements in this table via ajax and tried to disable scrolling when kids < 11 and enabled scrolling back when kids > 10 but couldn't quite figure it out. Any thoughts?

Comment: Search clearinterval. I can't fully give you an answer on this one cause it isn't straight forward but I'm pretty sure clearinterval is the route you will have to go. And each time you add one you reset the setinterval.

Comment: @mkweick Hi, I am trying to create a similar script. I too dynamically add and remove rows from my table but can't get this to work. Is it possible that you could pass on how you dynamically added rows to your table. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @DCJones it is likely that you are using dynamically created content that is causing the issues you mention. Usually in the case of dynamically created content you want to target the body and target classes or specific tags. However, without you creating another question and asking for help on that, I don't believe you will get the help you need.

Comment: @Cayce K many thanks for your reply. I now have this working in a fasion. I have it working only if I display the data in a table that is NOT automatically generated. I am now working to get it to work where the data is display using JQuery and Json to create the table. But the automatic scroll loop is not. With that said, I have asked another question on that subject. JQuery - Table rows not automatically scrolling.